# Обновление переменной внутри цикла

Tags: python

**ЗАДАЧА**: Напишите функцию `who_are_you_and_hello()`, которая читает имя пользователя из стандартного ввода, пока он не введет его в правильном формате, а затем здоровается. Приветствие должно быть в форме: "Привет, {имя}!". После вывода надо не забыть перевести курсор на новую строку.
Если пользователь ввёл имя в неправильной форме, функция должна считать его снова. Корректным считается имя, состоящее из одного слова, в котором нет символов кроме букв, первая буква заглавная, остальные — строчные.
После вывода приветствия функция должна завершить свою работу.
Обратите внимание: в вашей программе должна быть функция `who_are_you_and_hello`, но она не должна вызываться. Следите за тем, чтобы имя функции было написано верно.

Формат ввода:

```
who_are_you_and_hello()  
C клавиатуры вводится:  
Зачем тебе это знать?  
Хорошо, записывай  
Василий Пупкин  
Василий 1  
Вася1  
Вася!  
ВАСЯ  
Вася  
И тебе привет  
Михаил?  
Михаил
```

Формат вывода:

```
Привет, Вася!
```

Мой код:

```
def who_are_you_and_hello():
    a = 0
    name = input()
    while a == 0:
        if ' ' not in name and name.isalpha() and name.istitle() and name[1:].islower():  
            a += 1
        else:
            name = input()
    print('Привет, ', name, '!', sep='')
```

Тест проходит

**Вопрос**: пока переменная `name` находилась внутри цикла, т. е.:

```
while a == 0:
    name = input()
```

Выходила ошибка:
Ожидаемый результат:

```
Привет, Вася!
```

Вывод:

```
Привет, Михаил!
```

С чем это связано?

Comment: while a == 0: очевидно же, цикл не запускается, name не инициализируется.

Answer (score 0):

самое главное в вашем коде нет повтора запроса ввода и нет сообщений о неправильном формате

```
def who_are_you_and_hello():
    while True:
        name = input("Введите ваше имя: ")
        if ' ' in name or not name.isalpha() or not name.istitle():
            print("Неправильный формат имени. Попробуйте снова.")
        else:
            print(f"Привет, {name}!")
            break
        print()  # переход на новую строку
who_are_you_and_hello()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]